# Python Enumerate

Tags: python, enumerate

I have a code listed below that accepts a list and then returns a new list with every second value removed.

Can someone explain to me how this code works? I understand that the enumerate function will put the list into a list of tuples. Example: [1,2,3,4,5] will go to (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5)

Question 1: In the code why is "val" listed before the for loop in the return statement and then listed a second time after the for?

Question 2: After the word "for" is i for index 0  of the resulting tuple from the enumerate?

Question 3: After the word "for" is val for index 1  of the resulting tuple from the enumerate?

CODE:

```
def remove_every_other(lst):

    return [val for i,val in enumerate(lst) if i % 2 == 0]



print(remove_every_other([1,2,3,4,5])) # [1,3,5]
```

Comment: Please read the basics on list comprehensions - almost every explanation available online will cover your questions.

Comment: It means exactly what it says, read left-to-right: a list, made using the `val` results, where each `i, val` pair is taken from `enumerate(lst)`, but only considering those pairs where `i % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Q1, this is just a [list comprehension syntax](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/).
In your function it creates a list and returns it.
It could be rewritten as a regular for loop, e.g.

```
def remove_every_other(lst):
    result = []
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result.append(val)
    return result
```

In Python list comprehension is a more natural way to do this same thing.
Answers to Q2 & Q3 are yes and yes.

I think the function would be easier to understand if it looked something like this

```
def remove_every_other(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if i % 2 != 0]
print(remove_every_other([1,2,3,4,5])) # [1,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "for" loop, this is a list comprehension syntax. `[val for i,val in enumerate(lst)]` would go over what `enumerate(lst)` yields, tuple by tuple, and put just the `val`-s into a new list. All of them. Hence, this would simply recreate the same list. Adding the condition `[val for i,val in enumerate(lst) if i % 2 == 0]` will make it take just the values the condition is true for, so only the ones where index is dividable by 2. As others have already mentioned, reading about list comprehension would be very helpful.

This said, you can do the same thing in a much simpler form. Specifically, just `lst[::2]`.